# python/pygame - how to display images randomly?

Tags: python, random, pygame

I'm new to coding, need help displaying one of the images at random on the screen. This is what I have so far...

```
number_two = pygame.image.load("two.png")
number_three = pygame.image.load("three.png")
number_four = pygame.image.load("four.png")



display_number = number_list(random.randint(0, 3))
display_number = pygame.transform.scale(display_number, 70, 80)
```

I have an error message saying: 
display_number = number_list(random.randint(0, 3))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Please give the full stack trace and the `number_list` definition.

Comment: Please show us more of your code, including the `number_list` definition as aluriak requested.

Comment: square brackets `number_list[random...]`, `number_list` is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to *call* `number_list` as if it was a function, because you've put parentheses after it. Instead, you want to access an item, so you'd use square brackets instead:

```
display_number = number_list[random.randint(0, 3)]
```

For this case, though, you could just use `random.choice` on the list instead to get a random item:

```
display_number = random.choice(number_list)
```

From the Python documentation:

> `random.choice(seq)`
>
> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

Create the number list, then refrence it using [] square brackets, not () parentheses.

```
number_two = pygame.image.load("two.png")
number_three = pygame.image.load("three.png")
number_four = pygame.image.load("four.png")

number_list = [number_two, number_three, number_four]

display_number = number_list[random.randint(0, 3)]
display_number = pygame.transform.scale(display_number, 70, 80)
```